# Correct way to specify JSON block size for PyArrow dataset?

Tags: pyarrow

**Question**: when reading newline delimited JSON files as a PyArrow dataset, what is the correct way to specify the JSON `block_size`?

**Context**

I have newline-delimited JSON files which I wish to convert to parquet.

This code worked for one set of files:

```py
# ... imports, schema definition

dataset = ds.dataset(
    'data/landing/type_one',
    format='json',
    schema=schema_type_one
)
ds.write_dataset(
    dataset, 
    'data/intermediate/type_one', 
    format='parquet',
    min_rows_per_group=3*512**2,
    max_rows_per_file=5*10**6
)
```

For another type of files (different data structure), my code was failing with `pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: straddling object straddles two block boundaries (try to increase block size?)`.  Some Googling took me to [this Github issue](https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/issues/2181), where one of the comments hinted at what my problem was:

> We're using the JSON loader of pyarrow. It parses the file chunk by chunk to load the dataset.
> This issue happens when there's no delimiter in one chunk of data. For json line, the delimiter is the end of line.
> So with a big value for chunk_size this should have worked unless you have one extremely long line in your file.

And in fact yes, I have some extremely long lines in my second set of files, so I need to increase the block size somehow.

`pyarrow.dataset.dataset` does not have a way to directly specify block size for JSON, but I was able to get it to work by specifying `format` as a `JsonFileFormat` object with specific `read_options`:

```py
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
from pyarrow._dataset import JsonFileFormat
from pyarrow.json import ReadOptions

# ... schema definitions

fileformat = JsonFileFormat(
    read_options=ReadOptions(block_size=5*2**20)
)

dataset = ds.dataset(
    'data/landing/type_two',
    format=fileformat,
    schema=schema_type_two
)

ds.write_dataset(
    dataset, 
    'data/intermediate/type_two', 
    format='parquet',
    min_rows_per_group=3*512**2,
    max_rows_per_file=5*10**6
)
```

However, this import makes me uncomfortable: `from pyarrow._dataset import JsonFileFormat`.  Whereas `pyarrow.dataset.ParquetFileFormat` is documented in the public API, I had to dig through the code to find the existence of `pyarrow._dataset.JsonFileFormat` which resides in a separate "private" `_dataset` package.

Is there a more "correct" way to achieve what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that at the time of this writing `JsonFileFormat` is simply missing from the documentation for `pyarrow.dataset`.  The documentation has `CsvFileFormat`, `IpcFileFormat`, `ParquetFileFormat` and `OrcFileFormat` but not `JsonFileFormat`.

In fact however, `pyarrow.dataset` imports `JsonFileFormat` along with the other file formats from `pyarrow._dataset`.

So instead of doing:

```py
from pyarrow._dataset import JsonFileFormat
```

one can directly do

```py
from pyarrow.dataset import JsonFileFormat
```

And then the `block_size` can be specified by providing an appropriately configured `pyarrow.Json.ReadOptions` object to `JsonFileFormat`, as shown in the original code in the question.

Comment: Opened https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/40575 to track the missing documentation